# Everywhere partially differentiable function satisfying $\lim_{t\to0}f(t, t^2) = \infty$

Tags: limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Does there exist a function $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that it has both partial derivatives in every point of $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $\lim_{t\to0}f(t, t^2) = \infty$?

Comment: "Differentiable" and "both partial derivatives exist everywhere" are not the same. The latter doesn't require continuity, for instance, which is exactly what you're going for here.

Comment: @TedShifrin of course! you're right, for some reason I saw $\lim_{t \to 0}$ as $\lim_{t \to \infty}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about Nate Eldredge's function (edit: it was proposed $x^2$ instead of $x^4$ in the denominator), but $$f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^{4}+y^{2}}$$
with $f(0,0)=0$ sure works.

Ps. Sorry I can't comment other answers (not yet!).